# Where to find vault credentials in Azure Recovery Services Vault?

Tags: azure

I am setting up bandwidth throttling for Azure Site Replication.  Anyhow when I am registering Azure Backup on on-premises VM, I am prompted for Azure Vault Credentials.

*"Select the vault credentials downloaded from the quick start page in the Microsoft Azure Backup Vault."*

Unfortunately I already probably ticked the box "do not show this again" for the Quick Start Page.

[image: registering Azure Backup Vault]

Comment: Have you gone back to Recovery Service Vault > Backup > Prepare infrastructure > Step 2, download vault creds

Comment: That resolved the issue, thank you!.  It was just a bit strange because the Download button was grayed out unless I checked the box "Already using the System Center Data Protection Manager or any other System Center product".  Which I am not using any of those products to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Recovery Service Vault > Backup > Prepare infrastructure > Step 2, download vault creds

Comment: This is *no longer correct* AFAICT. The link has moved to the bottom of the Properties tab!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a few months old but I inherited client and trying to do the same thing, but when I select the recovery services vaults in the azure portal, I only see the actual vaults, I don't see a backup section. but when I select one of the vaults is when I get presented with options but still no prepare infrastructure to re-download vault creds. now if I select properties under settings, I do get a section where I can download backup credentials. it is a file with name of vault and a .vaultcredentials file extension.

Comment: THANK YOU! The instructions are out of date it appears, as this is the only place I could find this!